# Magento Display Product Data in Custom Extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

In a custom Magento 1.8.x extension, I want to display product data but leverage ALL existing catalog/product core code.

It has been straight forward to copy/paste the product.info block (and children) from category.xml, inherit core functionality, but change blocks to use custom templates.  So far, all product data displays just fine except product price/availability.

Price/availability (for a simple product) is from block product.info.simple as part of the layout handle below.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

However, no matter where this layout xml is placed (in the extension layout or local.xml), price/availability do not render.  If product.info includes block product.info.simple directly it does render.  e.g.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="aydus/quickview/view.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
            <label>Product Extra Info</label>
        </block>
    </block>
    etc.
```

How do I display product price/availability using existing (or copying) these layout  handles?

Answer (score 1):

`<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>` is a special handle. Magento knows when it is displaying a simple product and magically* includes the XML. It is a bit like  for any updates to the category n. I suggest you create your own one like this for example:

```
<my_magic_price_availablity translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</my_magic_price_availablity>
```

Then anywhere in your XML that you want this handle to add the blocks into a layout (that already has a block named "product.info") you just need to add...

```
  <update handle="my_magic_price_availablity"/>
```

So in context, in local.xml, you might have

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  <update handle="my_magic_price_availablity"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```

`<update` means 'copy the contents of `my_magic_price_availability` as if I had typed it here'.

*If you don't believe in magic, then you should read the code here:

```
//file: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php
//class: Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View
//function: initProductLayout()
//...
        $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId());
        $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());
//...
```

So yes, `<PRODUCT_n>` can be used in local.xml if you want to specify blocks for a single product.

I suppose you could add those lines to your custom module - that might be a more general solution. `$update` is `$update = $controller->getLayout()->getUpdate();`